# Dataflow flex template fails with error "Unknown non-composite transform urn"

Tags: docker, kotlin, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run an Apache Beam flow using Google Cloud Dataflow Flex-template but the template I created continue to fail with the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transform ReadingFileFromSamples-Read-Impulse is not a composite transform but does not have a specified URN.
outputs {
    key: "org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<init>:397#bb20b45fd4d95138"
    value: "ReadingFileFromSamples/Read/Impulse.out"
}
```

The code is very simple Kotlin version of wordcount using Apache Beam v2.51.0:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("app.fp8.sample.kbeam.MainTK")
    val options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(*args).withValidation().`as`(IAppOptions::class.java)
    // options.gcpCredential = AppHelper.getGCloudCredentials(options.serviceAccountPath)

    // Define pipeline
    val pipe = Pipeline.create(options)
    pipe.apply(
        "ReadingFileFromSamples",
        TextIO.read().from(options.inputFilePattern)
    ).apply(
        "CountWords",
        WordCounterTransform(options.outputCountGreaterThan)
    ).apply(
        "OutputLogs",
        PassthroughTransform<String> {
            println("Result -> $it")
        }
    )

    // Run the pipeline
    try {
        logger.info("Start running pipeline reading from {}", options.inputFilePattern)
        pipe.run()
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        logger.error("Job failed due to runtime exception: ${e.message}", e)
        exitProcess(1)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.error("Unexpected Exception: ${e.message}", e)
        exitProcess(1)
    }
}
```

The error is clearly on the step of `TextIO.read()` where the `inputFilePattern` is set to `gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/*`.  The error seems to imply that I am attempting to read a `Impulse.out` which is not true.

Any idea what that error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I came across the issue below that is similar to the question I raised:

https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/28034

I am too building a fat jar and the moment that I replaced one jar with  all the required jars to the `--jar` method of `gcloud dataflow flex-template build`, I finally managed to run the flex template in Dataflow.

Which made me wonder why Google doesn't allow passing wild card into the [--jar](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/flex-template/build#--jar) option.  The lack of this wild card option is what led me to create fat jar in the first place.